# $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ as Markov Kernel

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the following proposition:

Let $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ be a non-negative function jointly measurable in $(x,y)$ and satisfying:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx=1 \quad \forall y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Then, $K(y,dx)=f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ defines a Markov kernel.

When I am trying to prove this, there are two things I need to show:

1. $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ is a measure.
2. $y\mapsto \int_B f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ is measurable for every $B\in B(\mathbb{R})$.

It is easy to show $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$ is a measure because it satisfies what a conditional PDF satisfies. For (2), it says I need to use the Fubini's theorem to show its $F_2$-measurability (i.e. Borel-sigma algebra-measurable). How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Tonelli/Fubini theorem, which essentially says for $\sigma $-finite measures, that
$$\int_{X\times Y} g(x,y) (\mu \otimes \nu) (dx,dy) = \int_Y\Big( \int_X g(x,y)\mu(dx) \Big)\nu(dy),$$
whenever $g$ is $\mu \otimes \nu$ integrable. Now take a look at the righthand side, where we integrate $y\mapsto \int_Yg(x,y)\mu(dx)$, so this function is integrable, but integrable functions are definitely also measurable, and if you look up a proof for the theorem, then there should also be a proof that this function is measurable.

Technically $g$ doesn't have to be integrable, it also holds when $g$ is non-negative and measurable, which is also the case for your conditional density function.

If we apply Tonellis theorem to the non-negative function $f_{X|Y}(x|y)1_{B}$ and $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure and $\nu$ any $\sigma $-finite measure (for example the Lebesgue measure), then it follows that
$$y\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R}f_{X|Y}(x|y)1_{B}(x)dx = \int_B f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$$
must be measurable.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. A question: $y\mapsto \int_Yg(x,y)\mu(dx)$, so this function is simply a function $k(y)=\int_Yg(x,y)\mu(dx)$?

Comment: Yes. It is just a preference of notation.